# mysqldump makes 0bytes files

Tags: linux, mysql

I have a mysqldump line in crontab but it doesn't work, it just makes 0 bytes files:

```
0 0 * * *  mysqldump -u 'USERNAME' -p'PASSWORD' database| gzip -c > /mysqldumb/backupfile.`date +\%a`.sql.gz >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These redirections:

```
> /mysqldumb/backupfile.`date +\%a`.sql.gz >/dev/null
```

are performed from left to right and `>/dev/null` wins. The tool writes to `/dev/null`.

The file you're after ends up empty because this is how `>whatever` works: it creates the `whatever` file (if not already created) and truncates to zero size. Writing (or not writing) to the file happens later. In your case nothing writes to the `backupfile.*`.

If you want to write to the file specified, remove `>/dev/null` from the command line.

---

The title is

> `mysqldump` makes 0-byte files

It's not `mysqldump` that creates the empty file; `gzip` doesn't do this either.

Cron runs a shell, the shell sets up pipes and redirections *before* `mysqldump` and `gzip` are executed. The shell creates and truncates the file at this stage.

To see how it works, invoke

```
nonexistent-command > new-file
```

You will get `nonexistent-command: not found` or equivalent error, still `new-file` will be created.

Comment: So it's because im missing the > sign. It dosn't work?

Comment: @sbh7600 It's because you override "write to this file" by "write to `/dev/null`". Pick one.